# XPATH Query for Angular 10 Application

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath, pytest

I've finished building a simple web application using Angular 10 for the front end.  Now I'm in the process of writing a test script using pytest and Selenium web driver. I'm having trouble finding a reliable XPATH to check for the presence of text on the 'Star' page of my web app.  Included below is a pic of what the app looks like.

[image]

The test is relatively straightforward: navigate to the 'Star' page and check for the presence of a particular star (namely Sol) in the table.  That's it.  I can't seem to find a valid XPATH to the text, however.  I've been in Developer Tools trying different XPATH queries, but none of them work...for anything.  Buttons, text, etc.

I've also included the HTML code for the page in question: *show-star.component.html*

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right m-2" 
data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
(click)="addClick()"
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
>
    Add Star
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ModalTitle}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" 
          data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
          (click)="closeClick()" >
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <app-add-edit-star [star]="star" *ngIf="ActivateAddEditStarComp"> 
            </app-add-edit-star>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Star ID</th>
            <th>Star Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of StarList">
            <td>{{dataItem.StarID}}</td>
            <td>{{dataItem.StarName}}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1"
                data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                (click)="editClick(dataItem)"
                data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1"
                (click)="deleteClick(dataItem)">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd think it would be something as simple as //div[contains(text(),'Sol')] but nothing seems to work.
What exactly am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:**
The XPATH //td[contains(text(),'Sol')] doesn't match any selector in Dev Tools

[image: //td[contains(text(),'Sol')] doesn't match any selector in Dev Tools]

**Edit 2:** here is a snip of the code in Dev Tools

[image]

Comment: Could you include your pytest code or just the relevant test case with code? It will help to determine if something is missing there

Comment: The HTML that you've shared does not have any td that contains Sol, please share the relevant HTML for further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's wrapped in a div?

```
"//td[contains(text(),'Sol')]"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, either. I pasted your suggestion into Dev Tools and there was no matching selector.

Comment: Are you using the dev tools xpath syntax $x("pathhere")?  It would be this: $x("//td[contains(text(),'Sol')]")

Comment: that does not work either

Comment: This appears to work in Firefox Dev Tools but not in MS Edge. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: The edge syntax is a bit different: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/console/utilities